# Synchronize multiple node.js dynos

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm planning to host an express app on Heroku (I'm already experimenting with a single dyno).

I want to use [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) for maintenance tasks (doing some MongoDB updates). The question is, what's the simplest way to make sure the maintenance only runs once? All dynos would try to run the maintenance at the same time.

My current approach uses MongoDB's atomic upserts as some sort of semaphore (every dyno tries to set the flag for the current maintenance). But that's kinda ugly.

I'd like to not have a separate worker instance since it's really just a simple task that needs to be run once a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's what the Heroku Scheduler is good for (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler). If the execution of your update isn't taking too long it's the way to go. You write a JS script (e.g. schedule.js) that knows how to update your MongoDB, put it in your root and schedule it using the Heroku Scheduler (it comes with a trivial frontend) to invoke it (`node scheduler.js`) at the time desired.

Comment: Well, that sounds easy ;-). Haven't found that addon before or maybe I thought it would be too expensive. But if my tasks run once a day and take a few seconds this will only add up to some cents, if at all.

Comment: you get 750 free dyno-hours per app, meaning 31.25days of free computing time -> if your scheduled scripts don't consume more that quarter a day in a month with 31 days, you get it for free. In practice you've got to run 2 web dynos anyway since one dyno will go to sleep after 60mins idle time and need ~15 seconds to wake up when triggered by a routing event. (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos) -> If your app has only a single web dyno running, it will sleep - irrespective of the number of worker dynos. You have to have more than one web dyno to prevent sleeping.

Comment: I already know about this and plan to run at least two web dynos when we launch. Since Heroku bills every second a dyno runs (not just full hours, like EC2), I will probably have to pay some cents for the additional one-off dyno per month.